# Data Types supported in visual studio 2008

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, linq, types

I just downloaded and installed the latest Adventure Works database from http://www.codeplex.com/MSFTDBProdSamples/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=16040 to do some more playing around with LINQ and found that there are some data types that are not natively supported within Visual Studio 2008. I get the "One or more selected items contain a data type that is not supported by the designer." error message.

I found that the spatial data type is the issue in this case.

My questions are:

- What other data types are not
  inherently supported by Visual
  Studio that is in SQL Serve 2008?
- Why are these types not supported?

The second question is I guess the most puzzling to me. I can understand why not all data types would be supported from MySQL, Oracle, Postgre SQL and so forth. I would think that the SQLServer development group, might give a heads up to the Visual Studio development group, you know yell down the hall or something.

Comment: just FYI, Visual Studio is just an IDE, it is the .Net framework that defines the data types.  It might also help if you clarify what language you are using, although that doesn't directly affect the answers to your question.

Comment: I did not indicate language as it would be irrelevant in this case. I imagine it would be the same issue with VB, C#, F#, J#. Thanks for the help with the clarification of the framework however.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to this [blog post](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/bobb/post/SQL-Server-2008-data-types-in-LINQ-to-SQL-and-EF-they-(mostly)-did-it.aspx) it's everything except the spatial types (Geometry and Geography) and the HierarchyID data type.

As for why? Well they release support for most of the types in an update, as per this [blog bost](http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/2008/02/21/coming-soon-to-linq-to-sql.aspx) by the ADO.NET team, but that's the last LINQ to SQL entry. They seem to be only worried about the Entity Framework now. Who knows if we'll ever see a LINQ to SQL v2?

Answer (score 2):

SqlGeography and LINQ to SQL

Problem: Its a case when we use spatial data types (`Geometry`, `Geography`) supported by SQL Server 2008 in LINQ to SQL.

Solution:
    Step 1: Create a view that is based on the desired table and that does not include the unsupported data type (just include the column as: `CAST(geography_column AS VARBINARY(MAX))`

Step 2:   Drag the view from `Server Explorer` / `Database Explorer` onto the designer.